# How to setup AirPort Extreme 802.11n to connect to my wifi and share its ports?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, airport-extreme, airport-express

Is there any way to force my AP Extreme to act as an wifi client and share it´s ethernet ports? This is no problem with my AP express, but I want to utilize the gigabit ports and switch capabilities on the AP Extreme. Im not looking for WDS type solutions as I am finally able to run a pure 5 Ghz single router setup and cover my whole house (wds will degrade performance)
I am willing to try just about anything as the Extreme has little value to as is.

Any alternative ideas welcome and as an last resort I am considering using the Express to feed the Extreme (and switch of the wifi) but the antennas on the Extreme are superior to the Express and will give a better connection.
Regards Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve, but let me clear up some things first:

- Setting the AiE as a wi-fi client is possible in Airport Utility under network.
- All connected ethernet devices through the AiE should be shared within your (local) network.
- What exactly do you mean by 'switch' capabilities on the AiE? I doubt it has them
- WDS does indeed degrade performance and incredibly decrease security
- How are you able to run a pure 5GHz router setup? Afaik it isn't possible to turn off the 2.4GHz band.

Please reply to this answer with further question as I'll be glad to answer them.